# Error Message: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickShare [class android.view.View]

Tags: java, android, onclick, share, imagebutton

I am receiving the above error message when I click the image button. I am not sure what the issue is here. All I am trying to do is take the text in the text box ad share it.

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#001a90" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="onClickShare" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```java
public class rssitemview extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rssitemview);
    }

    public void onClickShare(View view){
        TextView txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtDesc.getText());
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Text..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(rssitemview.this, "There are no means to share.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use the same layout for multiple activities ?

Comment: The only other use, is calling the same Layout from a different activity that displays the item. Could that be the issue? This is the call `rssadaptor = new RSSListAdaptor(rssfeed.this, R.layout.rssitemview,itemlist,params[0]);`

Comment: Try after initializing the ImageButton

Comment: you need to declare  `public void onClickShare(View view)` in every activity where you are setting that layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to add the OnClickListner inside the getView class of the ListAdaptor.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            ImageButton whBtn = null;
            ImageButton fbBtn = null;
            ImageButton twBtn = null;

            if(null == view)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)rssfeedFragment.this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
                whBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.whBtn);
                fbBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fbBtn);
                twBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.twBtn);
            }

            if (whBtn != null) {
                whBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Code goes here
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            if (fbBtn != null) {
                fbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Code goes here
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            if (twBtn != null) {
                twBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Code goes here
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```